# Annotating a matplotlib figure with a matrix of variable row number

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, visualization

I am trying to automate some plotting tasks I have in Python, one of which requires annotating a plot with a square matrix. The row number of the matrix is subject to change.
I am attempting to use latex and matplotlib to do this, but am unable to get a valid Latex string:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Number of rows of matrix
N=4

#create what I believe to be the valid Latex instruction:
beginning="$ \\left( \\begin{array}{"
formatting=N*'c'+'}\n'
array_rows=(N-1)*((N-1)*'%f & '+'%f \\\\\n')
final_row=(N-1)*'%f & '+'%f '
end="\\end{array} \\right) $"

matrix=beginning+formatting+array_rows+final_row+end

#generate some random values for the matrix and put them in a flat tuple
a=np.random.randn(N,N)
vals=tuple(a.flatten())

#attempt to annotate a plot:
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1)
ax.annotate(matrix % vals,(0.2,0.2))
```

'print(matrix)' returns:

```
$ \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
%f & %f & %f & %f \\
%f & %f & %f & %f \\
%f & %f & %f & %f \\
%f & %f & %f & %f \end{array} \right) $
```

which is what I expect, but 'ax.annotate(matrix % vals,(0.2,0.2))' returns:

```
'RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'$ \\\\left( \\\\begin{array}{cccc}0.587986 & -0.670847 & 1.424638                 & 1.416569 \\\\1.961583 & 2.134095 & 0.296239 & -0.737057 \\\\0.311355 &         0.018828 & 0.031258 & -1.443867 \\\\0.964141 & 0.686492 & -1.367708 &         -1.353436\\\\end{array} \\right) $''

'! Undefined control sequence.
l.13 ...87986 & -0.670847 & 1.424638 & 1.416569 \1.961583 & 2.134095     
& 0.296...'
```

I haven't been able to work out where the problem is, although it seems to be to do with the backslashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve that by preceding each string with an `r` character, this will turn the strings into byte strings which can then be parsed by LaTex and render the matrix correctly. This does mean the strings have to be *verbatim* LaTex syntax, consider the following example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=4

beginning=r"$ \left( \begin{array}{"
formatting=N*r'c'+r'}'
array_rows=(N-1)*((N-1)*r'%f & '+r'%f \\')
final_row=(N-1)*r'%f & '+r'%f '
end=r"\end{array} \right) $"

matrix=beginning+formatting+array_rows+final_row+end

a=np.random.randn(N,N)
vals=tuple(a.flatten())

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1)
ax.annotate(matrix % vals,(0.2,0.2))
```

[image: Plot annotated with LaTex matrix]

This does make the syntax formatting a little nasty if you try to use `print matrix` because the `\n` characters must be stripped from the input since they get parsed into `\\`. However the compiled LaTex annotation will be correct.

Comment: @Bazingaa I’ve spent more than my fair share of time beating my head against using LaTex in matplotlib I actually just had to look at some old code haha. Thanks for the vote